# How can I tell Salesforce their CPQ Developer Org is BROKEN when their Submit Case is BROKEN?

Tags: timezone, currency, language, superbadges, salesforce-support

My original objective was to do the prework setting up a CPQ Developer Org for [Superbadge Billing Specialist](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_billing_specialist)

The first bullet on "Pre-work and Notes" declares:

> Default currency is USD and default time zone is PST (necessary for dates and schedulers).

Well, I happen to be living in Berlin and every time I want/need to create a new Developer org, Salesforce gets it into its misguided "head" to help me by setting up the new org in German (couldn't they ask on the signup?)

Okay, fine, well, I know how to fix that -- usually.

So, after first navigating to "Sprache & Zeitzone" in my settings and setting that to "Englisch" so I can see/understand what I am doing, I then go to "Setup" and type Company in the quick find (being very careful not to hit "Enter" because this will break the filter).

Now I click on "Company Information" and get a lovely message which declares:

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.

As my user is a System Administrator, this is clearly a bug.
Maybe there is some way to hack this problem with Permission Sets, but I don't know it and in addition to completing the superbadge, I want to be a responsible netizen, so I decide to [contact Salesforce Support](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=home).

I complete the form including the following message:

> I'm a Salesforce specialist living in Berlin.
>
> Putting aside the INCREDIBLY ANNOYING assumption that I want my new
>   developer orgs to be created with German as the default language
>   (couldn't you make this part of the setup form?), this TERRIBLE
>   ASSUMPTION, along with a possible defect is making it impossible for
>   me to complete prepare a CPQ Developer Org to complete Billing
>   Specialist superbadge.
>
> Specifically, when I try to view or edit the "Company Information", I
>   get this error:
>
> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.
>
> Click here to return to the previous page.
>
> As (username) bmk@XXXXXXX.XXXX is the System Administrator of this new
>   org, this seems to be a defect.
>
> Can you fix this? Or tell me what to do so that I can fix this? Or
>   tell me what to do -- aside from moving or setting up a VPN -- so
>   Salesforce will stop making terrible assumptions about how to set up
>   my developer orgs, playgrounds, etc.?
>
> Thank you!
>
> -Brian Kessler.
>   +49 176 6947 XXXX

and verify my humanity,

However, the "Submit Case" button remains disabled.

Speculating there could be a conflict with a Chrome extension, I turn them all off.  No luck.  Then I try Firefox, Microsoft Edge Dev, and Brave browser.  No, the submit case button still won't enable.

Is there anything I can do to get Salesforce to fix this issue?
Is there any way I can complete the superbadge even if Salesforce does nothing to fix this issue?

Comment: The Trailhead team is quite active on Twitter. That said, the Submit Case function on Trailhead support worked fine for me yesterday, and a quick peek suggests it's operating as expected today.

Comment: @DavidReed, I'm not sure what your expectations are but when four browsers refuse to enable the button without indicating any errors or actions i should take to get the button enabled, I'd say that fails to meet _my_ expectations.  I don't know if my location being Germany - which apparently screws up creating orgs - can somehow be relevant.

Comment: How about manually enabling it via your browser's inspector/debugger?

Comment: @PhilW, Good idea but it (the support form) seems to be working now...  :-)